# how to access a point in the type of PCLPointCloud2

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

Is this correct to obtain a point cloud from a STL file 'sphere.stl' by the following code?

```
pcl::PolygonMesh mesh;
pcl::io::loadPolygonFileSTL("sphere.stl", mesh);
pcl::PCLPointCloud2::Ptr ThisCloud = boost::make_shared<pcl::PCLPointCloud2>(mesh.ThisCloud);
```

Then, how to access each point of 'ThisCloud'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I converted the `pcl::PCLPointCloud2` to a `pcl::PointCloud<PointXYZ>`:

```
...
// conversion
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr vertices( new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> );
pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2( mesh.cloud, *vertices ); 

// access each vertex 
for( int idx = 0; idx < vertices->size(); idx++ )
{
   pcl::PointXYZ v = vertices->points[ idx ];

   float x = v._PointXYZ::data[ 0 ];
   float y = v._PointXYZ::data[ 1 ];
   float z = v._PointXYZ::data[ 2 ];
}
```

Comment: It seems in pcl-1.8, there is no fromROSMsg.

Comment: I updated the code and replaced fromROSMsg with fromPCLPointCloud2.  This worked for me with pcl 1.8.

Comment: I have a file of sphere.stl. From this, I have successfully obtained a set of points by pointXYZ type according to your information. I want to fill inside of sphere with points, too. Is there any method in PCL? Generally speaking, I want to fill with points inside of an object represented by STL file format in a manner of similar distance with respect to points of surfaces.

Comment: I don't know if I understood right. You can create a new point with pcl::PointXYZ newPoint( x, y, z ) and add this point to the cloud with vertices->push_back( newPoint ). If you know the center and radius of the sphere, it will be easy to generate these points (vectors, vertices). But I doubt that there is a dedicated function in pcl for exactly that purpose. Maybe you can make a new question about that.

Comment: Is there a built in way to preserve not just the points but the normals from stl as well?

Comment: That's an interesting question. Likely the normals are in the cloud as well. One can concatenate a PointCloud<PointXYZ> and a PointCloud<PointNormal> to a new point cloud. Here is an example http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/concatenate_fields.php . I could imagine loadPolygonFileSTL is doing that as well. It is possible that one can access the normals with pcl::PointNormal aNormal = vertices->points[idx]